# Deducing function of two variables from its partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, linear-pde

I am fighting with a very simple system of linear PDEs, which solution I think it is straightforward, however, I cannot write it down in a formal way. 
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial X\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)}{\partial x_{1}}=f\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)\\
\frac{\partial X\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)}{\partial x_{2}}=g\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)
\end{array}\right. $$

I would like to write the solution as an integral of $f$ and $g$. In this way I can also work out the boundary conditions.

Can I write it as some sort of  $X\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)=\int\ ?\ dx_{1}\ dx_{2}+ Constant$?

Just to give an idea, at the end, a boundary condition could be e.g. $X(x_1=0,x_2) = 0$ but I'd like to be general.

Comment: You might need $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}$ for this to even have a solution. In that case, $\pmb{v} := (-f,-g,0)^{\top}$ is a conservative vector field, for which a scalar potential $X$ ($\nabla X = - \pmb{v}$) can be calculated by using line integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate the first equation w.r.t. $x_2$ and second equation w.r.t. $x_1$. The equality of mixed partials holds for smooth solutions, so that $f_{x_2} = g_{x_1}$ must be satisfied.
Now, integrate the first differential equation w.r.t. $x_1$ as follows:
$$
X(x_1,x_2) - X(a,x_2) = \int_{a}^{x_1} f(\xi,x_2)\, d\xi \, .
$$
Then, injecting this expression in the second differential equation gives
$$
\int_{a}^{x_1} f_{x_2}(\xi,x_2)\, d\xi + X_{x_2}(a,x_2) = g(x_1,x_2)-g(a,x_2) + X_{x_2}(a,x_2) = g(x_1,x_2) \, ,
$$
which is naturally satisfied. Of course, if we integrate the second equation first, we get
$$
X(x_1,x_2) - X(x_1,b) = \int_{b}^{x_2} g(x_1,\eta)\, d\eta \, .
$$
Both expressions are linked through the condition $f_{x_2} = g_{x_1}$. You may also have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259705) and related links.

For a boundary condition of the form $X(0,x_2)=0$, we find
$$
X(x_1,x_2) = \int_0^{x_1} f(\xi,x_2)\, d\xi
$$
by setting $a=0$.